# Software for Mirroring an Android 4.3 display onto a computer

Tags: android, screen-sharing

I have Samsung Galaxy Grand having  Android 4.3,

which is rooted and it has USB debugging enabled.

It's display is broken, but it responds to touch.

Im trying to mirror my phone onto a computer and control my phone through my PC.

I tried using visor , it apparently doesn’t support jellybean SDK, I haven’t found other software which supports jellybean SDK.

## Main Question

Please suggest me a software which supports screen Mirroring onto a pc In Android jelly bean SDK

## Requirements

1. Must support jelly bean (4.3)
2. Should run on windows 7
3. The application should have decent FPS 23-30
4. must support phone control
5. If it can run over WiFi, without requirement that's a bonus

(if possible)

6. Also if i view and control my device on an iPadOS device that's also a bonus.

PS. I have had success with [ScreenCast](https://xsavikx.github.io/AndroidScreencast/) but its FPS is really low.

Comment: Have you tried [Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/) or [AndroidScreencast](https://xsavikx.github.io/AndroidScreencast/). See: [How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5652/3573)

Comment: I haven't ,but I'll try them now and let you know how it goes, thanks for answering 

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/how-do-i-project-the-screen-of-my-android-phone-for-a-presentation was perfect!!!, if you could transform your comment into an answer ill Acept it right away

Comment: Which one worked for you?

Comment: android screencast, also it would have been nice if the dev added wifi feature eliminating the need of cable, isn't it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main list for screen sharing/mirroring apps is at:

[How do I project the screen of my Android phone for a presentation?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5652/3573)

However as you are using an older Android 4.3 device, some of the publisher like Visor may have deprecated support and you would have to find those APKs at mirror sites.

For basic screencasting/mirroring:

**On rooted device**

[AndroidScreencast](https://xsavikx.github.io/AndroidScreencast/)

As AndroidScreencast uses `adb`, you can connect via Wifi

- Connect Android phone and host machine to same WiFi network
- Connect Android phone to host machine using **USB cable** (to start with)
- Run `adb tcpip 5555` from a command prompt
- Run `adb shell "ip addr show wlan0 | grep -e wlan0$ | cut -d\" \" -f 6 | cut -d/ -f 1"` to obtain the phone's IP address
- Disconnect USB cable and run `adb connect <ip_address>:5555`

When adb tcpip 5556 is not responding, remove your data cable and reconnect cable

- Run adb shell netcfg - for finding phone ip.
- Run adb connect ip:5556 the device will be successfully added.
- Run adb devices - list all devices connected

and now finally unplug device and

- Run adb devices

you should see y.o.ur.ip:5556          devices

Verify connection with logcat output by running `adb logcat`

And make sure that AndroidScreencast is configured to use your `adb server`, see: https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast#run-adb-server-on-your-own

As you've had poor frame rate, this is a known issue:
https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast/issues/1

**On non-rooted device**

**[Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/)**

From what I recall it was using repeated `adb screencap` commands as prior to Android 5.0 you needed root to use device specific hacks to get "good" frame rate.

**[minicap](https://github.com/openstf/minicap)**

is another project which doesn't require root.

From their README:

> To capture the screen we currently use two methods. For older Android versions we use the ScreenshotClient, a private API in AOSP. For newer versions we use a virtual display, which also requires access to private APIs. The frames are then encoded using SIMD-enabled `libjpeg-turbo` and sent over a socket interface.

Which looks hopeful for older devices, but I haven't used it and don't know if there are any compatibility issues with your specific hardware.

Comment: even though my phone us rooted , FPS on androidscreencast is really bad

Comment: I used Droid@Screen for my presentations, but otherwise pre-5.0 devices had low frame rate. Did find another project called [minicap](https://github.com/openstf/minicap) in the AndroidScreencast issue thread: https://github.com/xSAVIKx/AndroidScreencast/issues/1#issuecomment-302949251 but honestly don't expect much on older devices.

Comment: CMD does nothing when i type adb tcpip 5555

Comment: If you searched and didn't find a solution, you are better off asking a new question if related to `adb`.

Comment: @Morrison_Chang I found the solution and i have added that into your answer , pl accept it so other users can benefit.Although wifi connection further decreases FPS. Or should i install custom ROM and use modern app?